# Add Membership Token to PDF Template Joomla

Tags: civimember, joomla, tokens, templates

I have been banging my head on this for a few days.  I created a PDF Template for our members so I can run a search of members in Expired or Grace, then PDF a letter reminding them to pay their membership.  I see the tokens for contacts, however cannot figure out how to add a token for Membership Type.  Any suggestions

Joomla 3.4.1 CiviCrm 4.6.0

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for Contacts or Memberships?  By default, Basic and Advanced Search return Contacts.

Your search needs to return Memberships, not Contacts if you want the membership tokens to be available in the PDF letter.

a) use Search >> Find Memberships

b) use Search >> Advanced Search and set "Display results as" to Memberships

In both cases you should have the "Print PDF Letters for Memberships" action that will let you include the Membership Type token.