# membership tokens not showing for mail in CiviMail

Tags: civimail, tokens

Using CiviCRM 4.7.24 and WordPress 4.8.2.

I'm trying to send an email with membership information in it. It works fine with a Print to PDF, but not with an email. I am using Find Membership to get the contacts (thanks to [Add Membership Token to PDF Template Joomla](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/add-membership-token-to-pdf-template-joomla)) for pointing this out. So why is it different for emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some tokens are only available when sending from 'that context'. Fuzion made an extension some time ago to get around this and hopefully you will find it provides what you need.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken)